# Trace Minimization of Covariance Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a matrix X whose rows contain observations collected at some locations.
Can someone explain how trace minimization of covariance matrix $XX^T$ can lead to orthogonal / mutually independent observations being selected from a larger set. Some mathematical explanation will be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you elaborate or provide some reference about the property?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot make sense of all this.

Comment: @leonbloy Can you be specific which part of the question is confusing or unclear. I can elaborate further.

Comment: The question statement is not all clear. "Minimize the trace of a covariance matrix". You can't minimize something if you don't specify which are the variables and which are the constraints.

Comment: I dimly suspect that it could be related to in signal processing is known as the "whitening" property of the optimal predicion error filter (the filter that minimizes the expected squared error of the prediction -which would correspond to the trace of its covariance matrix- gives as result an "white", uncorrelated -i.e., diagonal covariance- output). But that's just a wild guess. Eg: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~tabus/course/ASP/LectureNew7.pdf

Comment: @leonbloy The diagonal of covariance matrix contains variance of individual observations. So when I say minimize the trace of covariance matrix then it is subject to the minimization of individual variances of observations. Whitening is related but what I intend is more closely related to condition numbers of a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

For a random vector $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with covariance matrix $\Sigma_X$, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\|X\|^2]&=\mbox{Tr}(\Sigma_X)\\
&=\sum_i\lambda_i(\Sigma_X)\\
&\ge n\left(\prod_i\lambda_i(\Sigma_X)\right)^{1/n}\\
&=n\det(\Sigma_X)^{1/n}\\
&\ge \frac{n}{2\pi e}e^{2h(X)/n},
\end{align}
where the first inequality is AM-GM and the second inequality follows from the fact that differential entropy $h(X)$ is maximized when $X$ is Gaussian.

Your question relates to equality being achieved in the first inequality.  This only happens when the spectrum of $\Sigma_X$ is flat i.e. $\Sigma_X=\lambda I$, which implies that the components of $X$ must be uncorrelated (and hence independent, if $X$ is Gaussian).